# Log the dependencies in console for requirejs

Tags: console, dependencies, requirejs

Is there any trick to log the modules being loaded by require.js in the console?
e.g. 
Loading jQuery
Loading Underscore
Loading Backbone

I need this to understand how much time it is taking to download each module and log the same to test it under different environments.

Thanks,
Mandar Katre

Comment: Isn't the Network tab of Firebug or equivalent enough?

Comment: yeah, I did not want to use Fiddler or network tab and actually monitor the requests, since it involves starting the capturing and we can have too many requests on the wire. But this is definitely an option. Require js should have had this option to log the loaded modules and a flag to disable logging. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something similar to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/rBfTH/2/), and use **the internal API** [`onResourceLoad`](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Internal-API:-onResourceLoad). This won't give completely accurate load times, but it will give you an idea of which modules have been requested, and how long after a given start time they had finished being loaded.

```
<script>
require = {
    paths: {
        "jquery": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3",
        "underscore": "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min"
    },
    shim: {
        "underscore": {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "_"
        }
    }
};
</script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.8/comments/require.js"></script>
<script>
// https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Internal-API:-onResourceLoad
requirejs.onResourceLoad = function(context, map, depArray) {
    var duration = new Date() - start;
    console.log("onResourceLoad", duration + "ms", map.id);
}
</script>
```

and this JS

```
start = +new Date();

require(["jquery", "underscore"], function() {
    // log the global context's defineds
    console.log("require.s.contexts._.defined", require.s.contexts._.defined);
});
```

Produces this output in the test:

```
onResourceLoad 140ms jquery
onResourceLoad 167ms underscore
require.s.contexts._.defined  Object {jquery: function, underscore: function}
```